# Pioneer3-dx - ROSARIA or p2os? rosws or catkin?

Tags: ros, catkin, pioneer-3dx, rosaria, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm just getting starting with my Pioneer3Dx and it appears that Rosaria is the better choice today over p2os (based on ongoing support).  Is that correct?

What is the correct way to install and use the Rosaria package?  There seems to be contradictory information...  This page "http://www.ros.org/wiki/sig/robots/Pioneer" says Rosaria has been updated to catkin, but this page "http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA" has instructions using rosws.

Can someone provide the latest and greatest steps for installing and building Rosaria?

Thanks!
Gershon

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59392/pioneer3-dx---rosaria-or-p2os?--rosws-or-catkin?/) by [gershon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4399/gershon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2013-03-27

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Gershon,

I've edited the tutorial on ROS Wiki today to reflect the changes between the fuerte and the catkinized (groovy) version. However, there is still a problem with the current python-rosdep package that prevents the smooth installation of catkinized ROSARIA. You could grab the latest [rosdep](https://github.com/ros/rosdep) and install from source.
Dereck Wonnacott has put together a document to get his students started using ROS on a Pioneer 3-AT, perhaps you will find it useful: https://goo.gl/kQEyA.

I'd be grateful if you tried the updated tutorial and reported if you found any problem.

Best,
JKS

---

Originally posted by [JKS](https://answers.ros.org/users/357/jks/) with karma: 306 on 2013-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gershon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4399/gershon/) on 2013-03-28**:
The updated tutorial did not work for me.  It fails at this point:
dev@Pioneer3dx-laptop:~/catkin_ws/src$ wstool update amor-ros-pkg
ERROR in config: Command requires a target workspace.

**Comment by [JKS](https://answers.ros.org/users/357/jks/) on 2013-03-28**:
Maybe I should remove that command, since wstool wasn't used for setting the environment and adding the amor-ros-pkg repository. It was "updated" by the cloning of the repository in the previous step. Note that new python-rosdep package was released yesterday! :)

**Comment by [gershon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4399/gershon/) on 2013-03-29**:
I really could not get very far with the instruction on the ROS wiki, but the Dereck Wonnacott document https://goo.gl/kQEyA was amazing!  totally unblocked me.  I had to work through a couple small hiccoughs, but working great now.

**Comment by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) on 2013-05-08**:
Hey, I am in the same boat as you Gershon, before I start on Derecks commands, what hiccoughs did you have? and how did you get around them?
Edit: Further question, has the wiki been updated and can ROSaria now be smoothly installed based on the wiki?